# Vim says its installed but not opening files

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, vim

I have been using vim for a while now on my ubuntu (16.04 LTS) desktop, but for past few days, something seems to be wrong as when i try to open file using vim it says

The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:

- vim
- vim-gnome
- vim-tiny
- vim-athena
- vim-athena-py2
- vim-gnome-py2
- vim-gtk
- vim-gtk-py2
- vim-gtk3
- vim-gtk3-py2
- vim-nox
- vim-nox-py2
  Try: sudo apt install selected package.

I am pretty sure my vim is installed but nevertheless when I try to install using the standard, `sudo apt-get install vim`, it says

> vim is already the newest version (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2)

I don't understand the problem. Thought about trying out emacs for a change, but I would like to know if there is any resolution for this. I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Update:
I tried `dpkg -L vim`, which showed me:

```
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/vim
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/vim
/usr/share/bug/vim/script
/usr/share/bug/vim/presubj
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/share/doc/vim
```

So I used, vim.basic myfilename, which seems to be working for opening files, but still can't use vim.

UPDATE:
**output of dpkg -l 'vim*'  **

ii  vim                           2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 amd64               Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
un  vim-athena                                                (no description available)
un  vim-athena-py2                                            (no description available)
ii  vim-common                    2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 amd64               Vi IMproved - Common files
un  vim-doc                                                   (no description available)
ii  vim-gnome                     2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 amd64               Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GNOME2 GUI
un  vim-gnome-py2                                             (no description available)
un  vim-gtk                                                   (no description available)
un  vim-gtk-py2                                               (no description available)
un  vim-gtk3                                                  (no description available)
un  vim-gtk3-py2                                              (no description available)
ii  vim-gui-common                2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 all                 Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
un  vim-lua                                                   (no description available)
un  vim-nox                                                   (no description available)
un  vim-nox-py2                                               (no description available)
un  vim-perl                                                  (no description available)
un  vim-python                                                (no description available)
un  vim-ruby                                                  (no description available)
ii  vim-runtime                   2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 all                 Vi IMproved - Runtime files
un  vim-scripts                                               (no description available)
un  vim-tcl                                                   (no description available)
rc  vim-tiny                      2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 amd64               Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version

**output of update-alternatives --display vim is:**

vim - auto mode
  link best version is /etc/vim
  link currently points to /etc/vim
  link vim is /usr/bin/vim
/etc/vim - priority 100
/usr/bin/vim.basic - priority 30
/usr/bin/vim.gnome - priority 60

Comment: Sounds like a problem with "alternatives". Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/950400/edit your post and show us `update-alternatives --display vim`

Comment: Edit askubuntu.com/posts/950400/edit your post and show us `dpkg -l 'vim*' `

Comment: Please be more specific about "can't use vim" - what doesn't work, and what do you expect?